# Remove file extensions for html files in firebase

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-hosting

In `firebase.json`, is there a way to rewrite (not redirect) all requests to the corresponding .html file but leave other extensions?

for example, `https://example.com/foo` will be the same as `https://example.com/foo.html`.

But `https://example.com/data` will **not** be the same as `https://example.com/data.xml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the `cleanUrls` option (as [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_html_extensions)) in `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
}
```