# How can I remove ".html" at the end of the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-hosting

I'm facing an issue with the URLs on my website. The website consists of multiple pages, all of which are .html files. The problem arises when I deploy the website on Firebase Hosting with a custom domain. The pages end up with custom URLs like this:

[www.customdomain.com/page1.html](http://www.customdomain.com/page1.html) (for example)

However, what I actually need is:
[www.customdomain.com/page1](http://www.customdomain.com/page1) (without the ".html" extension)

This issue occurs on every page except the home page, where the URL is simply [www.customdomain.com](http://www.customdomain.com).

I've been referencing the other pages using HTML like this:

```
<a href="page1.html" class="link-1">Click to go to page 1</a>
```

Is there a way to remove the ".html" from each URL on the website? It may not necessarily be related to Firebase Hosting; it could be a problem with the references.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static files on Firebase Hosting, you can [control `.html` extensions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_html_extensions) via the `cleanUrls` in the `firebase.json` file configuration file.

There's no need to upgrade to a dynamic website to get rid of the filename extensions.

Also see:

- [How to remove .html URL endings and configure redirects in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380765/how-to-remove-html-url-endings-and-configure-redirects-in-firebase)
- [Remove file extensions for html files in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681599/remove-file-extensions-for-html-files-in-firebase)
- [Firebase hosting URL needs .html to display a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173400/firebase-hosting-url-needs-html-to-display-a-page)

Comment: You are right, the solution was to add the `cleanUrls: True`, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

As per your explanation your site is static pages of .html pages and when you run your website at that time it will load with default page call index.html that's why it not showing to you any file name. when ever you make any static site then it will display extension of file when it browse it's default behavior.

Comment: That's exactly what is happening, I should upgrade the hosting to a dynamic website to avoid the ".html" slugs. Thanks for your help!